# Prove that $6$ is a divisor of $n^3 - n$ for all natural numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

How would you approach such a problem? Induction perhaps? I have been studying proof by induction, but so far I have only solved problems of this nature:

$$1 + 4 + 7 +\dots+ (3n-2) = \frac{n(3n-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: Hint: $(n-1)n(n+1) = n^3 - n$

Answer (score 3):

You can decompose $n^3-n = (n-1)n(n+1)$. So $n^3-n$ is a product of three consecutive integers, and in such a sequence you always have an even number and a multiple of $3$. Hence $n^3-n$ is a multiple of $6$.

By induction: the base case is $n = 0$, which is trivial. Now suppose $6$ divides $n^3-n$. Claim: $6$ divides $(n+1)^3-(n+1)$.
You have
$$(n+1)^3-(n+1) =n^3+3n^2+3n+1-n-1=n^3-n+3n(n+1).$$
Now observe that since $6$ divides $n^3-n$ you just need to show that $3n(n+1)$ is a multiple of $6$. But one between $n$ and $n+1$ is even, so $3n(n+1)$ is a multiple of $6$. Hence $6$ divides $(n+1)^3-(n+1)$.

Comment: thanks! stupid question, but is there a tip or trick to decompose that type of expressions, n^3 - n?

Comment: One more step then: $n^3-n = n(n^2-1) = n(n-1)(n+1)$.

Comment: I liked your first proofs is simple, but how do you justify it? It is simple to prove that such sequence contains an even number. By definition n + 1 is odd so n must be even. However how can you show that either (n - 1) or (n + 1) is a multiple of three?

Comment: With the same reasoning: if $n$ is a multiple of $3$ you are done. If it is of the form $3k+1$, then $n-1$ is a multiple of $3$. Finally, if it is of the form $3k+2$, then $n+1 = 3k+3 = 3(k+1)$, so $n+1$ is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Gibbs has already presented a perfect proof. However, there is another one, that does not involve decomposition of $n^3-n$ and is relatively straightforward.

To say $n^3-n$ is divisible by $6$ is the same as saying $n^3-n \equiv 0 \pmod 6$. Thus, once we compute $n^3-n \pmod 6$ for all possible $n$, we are done. By general algebra, this is the same as computing $n^3-n$ for all elements of the ring $\mathbb Z / 6 \mathbb Z$, and there are exactly $6$ elements in this ring, namely the equivalence classes of $0,1,\dots,5$ modulo $6$.

So, let's compute this $6$ values $\mod 6$:

$$
\begin{array}{ l|c }
n & n^3-n \\ \hline
0 & 0-0 \equiv 0 \pmod 6\\ \hline
1 & 1-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \\ \hline
2 & 8-2 \equiv 6 \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \\ \hline
3 & 27-3 \equiv 24 \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \\ \hline
4 & 64 - 4 \equiv 60 \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \\ \hline
5 & 125 - 5 \equiv 120 \equiv 0 \pmod 6
\end{array}
$$

As you can see, $n^3-n\equiv 0 \pmod 6$ holds for any $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$ P(n) : 6 |(n^3 - n) $

$ P(0) : 6 | 0 $

We assume $ P(k) $ is true and now we demonstrate that $ P(k+1) $ is true

$ P(k) : 6 |(k^3-k) $ that means $ k^3-k=6m $

$ P(k+1) : 6 |((k+1)^3-(k+1)) $

$ P(k+1) : 6 |(k^3+3k^2+2k) $

$ P(k+1) : 6 |(m+3k^2+3k) $

$ P(k+1) : 6 |(m+3k(k+1)) $

$ m $ is divizible by 6 and $ 3k(k+1) $ is divizible by 6 because the product of two consecutive natural numbers is divizible by 2

Comment: why does that makes it divisible by 6? 4 and 5 are consecutive natural numbers and their products is divisible by 2, but not divisible by 6.

Comment: Notice $ k(k+1) $ is multiplied by $ 3 $ and also $ k(k+1) $ is even so in it's prime factor will find $ 2 $ and $ 3 $ :)

Answer (score 0):

Without induction, just note that $n^3 - n = (n+1)n(n-1) = 6\binom{n+1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove by induction take the base case $n=0$ or $n=1$.

Then for the inductive step $$(n+1)^3-(n+1)=n^3+3n^2+3n+1-n-1=(n^3-n)+3(n^2+n)$$and the statement will be true if you can show that $n^2+n=n(n+1)$ is even. You can do that various ways, including a similar induction